# Чи можна вжити прислівник середньо у фразі "заробляю в середньому 5 тис. грн щомісяця"?

Tags: вживання-слів, різниця-між-словами, прислівники

Чи можливе вживання прислівника ***середньо*** замість ***в середньому*** з дієсловами, приміром *заробляти* або *втрачати*, коли хочу надати середнє значення? Як у реченні "Я заробляю середньо 5 тис. грн щомісяця." В розмовній звучить ніби гаразд.

СУМ дає приклад слова ***середньо***, коли йдеться про ознаку, яка не вирізняється від інших - почуваюся середньо.

Comment: Не можна, це просторіччя.

Comment: В цьому контексті краще вжити "близько" або "приблизно". Також можна сказати "в середньому", але не "середньо" - це помилка. І зауважте щодо періоду. Отже, українською ми кажемо: "Я заробляю приблизно 5 тис. грн на місяць", "Мої щомісячні витрати становлять близько 5 тис. грн."

Answer (score 0):

Якщо ми скажемо "середньо" в даному реченні, то це буде означати щось на кшталт "заробляю середньо/посередньо", а не "заробляю в рамках 5 тис. грн".

"В середньому" говорить нам про вимір величини, якийсь статистичний показник, порівняння, виведення "середини" з чогось.